# VBA copy non blank columns based on value

Tags: excel, vba

I tried this kind of code, but didnt work

```
Sub CopyRow()
'Declare variables
    Dim DataRg As Range
    Dim DataCell As Range
    Dim P As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim I As Long
'Set variables
    P = Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Q = Worksheets("Hello").UsedRange.Rows.Count
''Type If condition to relate the variables I and Q
    If I = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Hello").UsedRange) = 0 Then Q = 0
    End If
'Set range for Data
    Set DataRg = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:A" & P)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Apply the For loop
    For I = 1 To DataRg.Count
'Set Condition for "Hello" value
        If CStr(DataRg(I).Value) = "Hello" Then
'Apply command to copy cells
            DataRg(I).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Hello").Range("A" & Q + 1)
            Q = Q + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any idea how to create one module so that I can copy rows (not blank rows)? I have the "data" sheet, and the conditonal value/text is in row A.
For example I want:

-For each cell of A row, if text is "Hello", then copy row (only non blanks) to sheet "Hello", beginning from second row (first row has headers)

-For each cell of A row, if text is "Bye", then copy row (only non blanks) to sheet "Bye", beginning from second row (first row has headers)

-For each cell of A row, if text is "Greetings", then copy row (only non blanks) to sheet "Greeting", beginning from second row (first row has headers)

If it is complicated, I could use 3 different modules for each condition

Comment: So if a row has columns A-G and C/E have blanks, you want the values to go to A-E in Hello/Bye/Greeting respectively?

Comment: If for example in sheet Data cell A10 and this is the first cell which value is "Bye", and the value of cell : B10 is "bla", C10 blank, D10 blank, E10 "bli", F10 blank, G10 "blo" ... so your expected result in sheet "Bye" ---> cell A2 value is "bla", B2 is "bli" and C2 is "blo" ? Please CMIIW

Comment: I have data in columns A,B,C,D,E,f,G (in "data" sheet) so i dont need to copy the rest blank columns(H to -->XFD), because in each destination sheet ("hello", "Bye", "Greetings") in colums H,I, i have some dynamic calculated data, and i dont want the vba copy/paste process to overwrite them.

Comment: Could've just phrased "not entire row, only cells A:G". Could work with cases for the Hello/Bye/Greeting then. You want to check all cells in A-row but only check the A-column in your code, how comes? Also, is it possible to have multiple possibilities: Hello, Bye and/or Greeting in one row? Should you copy for each case then?

Comment: To make it clear I have 3 kind of data in cells of A column, and i want for each kind of value (Hello, Bye, Greetings) to copy the filled cells of each row, and paste them in the right sheet(sheet "Hello"). More specific for every cell of column A in sheet1, that has the value "Bye", then copy/paste this row ***without blank cells***, to the sheet "Bye". I want this also for the rest values (Hello and Greetings). Every sheet has already Headers